# In SQL, how do I insert a character every 2 spaces in a nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following value in a nvarchar

0011223344

This value will always be an even length.

I need to convert this value to 00\11\22\33\44

Using MSSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in SQL Server..

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(20) = '0011223344'
DECLARE @i int = 3
WHILE @i < LEN(@test)
BEGIN
    SELECT @test = STUFF(@test, @i, 0, '\')
    SET @i = @i + 3
END
SELECT @test
```

You could probably implement a more elegant solution using a numbers table.

Comment: Why @i = 3 and @i + 3?

Comment: Inserting after every 2nd character, so slashes will be at 3, 6, 9, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 create function changeFormat( @BeginWord varchar(10)) returns varchar(20)

  as
  begin
    declare @finalWord varchar(20)
    SET @finalWord='';
    SET @finalWord= @finalWord + substring(@BeginWord,1,2)+ '/';
    SET @finalWord= @finalWord + substring(@BeginWord,3,2)+ '/';
    SET @finalWord= @finalWord + substring(@BeginWord,5,2)+ '/';  
    SET @finalWord= @finalWord + substring(@BeginWord,7,2);  
    return @finalWord
 end;
```

//call the function

```
 select word, dbo.changeFormat(word) as Formateado from table1;

word    Formateado
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
11223344    11/22/33/44
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(10) = '0011223344'

SELECT LEFT(@Var, 2) + '\' + SUBSTRING(@Var, 3, 2)+ '\' + SUBSTRING(@Var, 5, 2)
        + '\' + SUBSTRING(@Var, 7, 2)+ '\' + SUBSTRING(@Var, 9, 2)
```

**Result**

```
00\11\22\33\44
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote you but I can speculate why someone would. The question asked about strings of variable but even length. Your answer presumes every string is exactly 10 char wide.

Comment: @Mark alright I get it now Thanks for point this out , I thought OP said it will be a fixed length My mistake.